# org-mode terminal table color adjustment from dark blue to something brighter

Tags: customization, org-mode

I use org-mode fully within the terminal and tables default to a dark blue color, I would like to make it a brighter color but have been coming up fruitless on searching for how.

I found [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-appearance.html) however i *only* want to change the tables within org-mode terminal and nothing else.

can anyone point me in the right direction?  I assumed it would be an easy configuration in my .emacs file or SETUP in the org file. but I am missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can custumiza org-table face:

```el
(custom-set-faces '(org-table ((t (:foreground "WhiteSmoke")))))
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you!  Brilliant -- for additional colors I looked here --> https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html